# Issue in accessing child model objects from parent model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-views

I am creating a blogging website. I want to display all the articles posted by any particular writer/user. I have created the 'Post' model as the child of the 'Writer' model. I wanna display all the articles of the user in his profile. But I can't access the Post('s title) from the parent class, i.e., Writer class.
(I searched a few answers from the internet. Didn't help.) I am getting the error: **'Writer' object has no attribute 'post_set'**

## models.py:

```
class Writer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='profile.png', upload_to = 'Bloggers')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='Blog Image')
    content = models.TextField()
    post_writer = models.ForeignKey(Writer,null=True, related_name="tags", related_query_name="tag", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

## views.py:

```
def profile(request, pk):
    writer = Writer.objects.get(id=pk)
    print(writer.post_set.all())
```

## Error received:

> **`'Writer' object has no attribute 'post_set'`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the relation in reverse is specified by the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). Since you wrote:

```
post_writer = models.ForeignKey(
    Writer, null=True, related_name='tags',
    related_query_name='tag', on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
```

it means you access these with:

```
def profile(request, pk):
    writer = Writer.objects.get(id=pk)
    print(writer.tags.all())
```

But it looks rather *odd* to specify this as `tags`/`tag` in the first place. Why not use `related_name='posts'`?